# warnings in OpenERP while nevigating from page?

Tags: javascript, odoo

I have some questions :

1. Is is possible to show a warning message while saving a record(in create) method like record saved successfully.

2.I want to show a warning message while nevigating from the page after clicking create and leaving page without save by clicking on some menu item ,backspace or back button of browser?

Answer (score 1):

1. I can't understand why you want to show a warning message on save when everything is goes  fine.
   Warning message is shown when something goes wrong or user break a rule eg. when user don't have a right to create a record of particular object and user try to create a record.

IMHO It is better to use a workflow to define the flow of process like we have a two state new and done default state is new when user create and enter all required field and click on save trigger a workflow and change state from new to done. That tell user that he complete the flow like wise you can put a state as you required.
for more detail on workflow please read from
http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/3_9_Workflow_Business_Process/index.html

2.I think this feature is already implemented in new upcoming version 7.0.

Comment: Heroic , I am completely agree with your answer but Here I have a requirement that I have to open a dialogue box on each saving record like "Record saved successfully". I may be vague in my question because warning goes in negative sense what I need is same but in positive sense.

And about 2nd yes there is something implemented like what I am asking in 7.0 but not all ,I mean I want to ask it at every form unload if form is not saved , this form unload may cause by any of keyboard back button,Browser back button or can be by clicking on a link somewhere in the form.

Comment: so u can create a new custom wizard to display success full save data message instead of warning message and trigger a wizard when save button is click.

Comment: Heroic: Wizard is not a solution for show a dialogue like, Record saved successfully.Wizard will look weird at this place. well but in one case I tried to launch wizard in create and write method , Off course it was not a case of waring, I could not succeed to launch wizard in create and write method. Do you think there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

strong textHi Yes sure you can raise Alert Message when saving record through JS script it is possible you have to write single line code in path addons/web/static/src/js/viewform.js

```
on_button_save: function() {
    var self = this;
    return this.save().done(function(result){
        **if (!confirm(_t("The record has been saved"))) {
            return false;
        }**
        self.trigger("save", result);
        self.reload().then(function() {
            self.to_view_mode();
            var parent = self.ViewManager.ActionManager.getParent();
            if(parent){
                parent.menu.do_reload_needaction();
            }
        });
    });
},
```